# Tensor product of integral $k$-algebras is integral domain

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I think I have heard and have seen examples about that tensor product of integral $k$-algebras need not be integral domain.

[But why this one claim so?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3403322/filtered-colimit-of-integral-domains-is-an-integral-domain)

Comment: The link doesn’t talk about tensor products.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, this is not true. The linked post talks about *filtered* colimits, but a tensor product is a colimit of a discrete diagram (and nontrivial discrete diagrams are not filtered).

Counterexample: let $k = \mathbb{R}$. Then $\mathbb{C}$ is an integral $k$-algebra, but $\mathbb{C} \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}$ is not.

Comment: I forgot to mention it in my comment to the OP, but there are two different meanings of “integral” and their phrasing is unclear…

Comment: Thank you , I see now what is actually a filtered (co)limit. I thought any diagram induces a filtered (co)limit.